# is there a way to rotate Rectangles2D like the hands of an analog clock in Java?

Tags: java

I have to create an analog clock in Java and to do so I used Rectangles2D as if they were the hands. Now I need a method that allows me to rotate them around the center of the quadrant, but I can not find anything that allows me to do it. I leave the code I wrote for now.

```
    Ellipse2D out, in;
    Rectangle2D h, m, s;

    public Graphics2DComponent() {
        out=new Ellipse2D.Double(500, 400, 500, 500);
        in=new Ellipse2D.Double(500, 400, 470, 470);
        h=new Rectangle2D.Double(500, 400, 5, 150);
        m=new Rectangle2D.Double(500, 400, 5, 200);
        s=new Rectangle2D.Double(500, 400, 5, 150);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;

        g2.setPaint(Color.GRAY);
        g2.fill(out);
        g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(in);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(h);
        g2.fill(m);
        g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(s);
    }
}

Timer seconds, minutes, hours;

public Clock() {
    super("Clock");
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Graphics2DComponent panel=new Graphics2DComponent();
    panel.out.setFrame(getWidth()/2-panel.out.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2-panel.out.getHeight()/2, panel.out.getWidth(), panel.out.getHeight());
    panel.in.setFrame(getWidth()/2-panel.in.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2-panel.in.getHeight()/2, panel.in.getWidth(), panel.in.getHeight());
    panel.h.setFrame(getWidth()/2-panel.h.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2-panel.h.getHeight(), panel.h.getWidth(), panel.h.getHeight());
    panel.m.setFrame(getWidth()/2-panel.m.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2-panel.m.getHeight(), panel.m.getWidth(), panel.m.getHeight());
    panel.s.setFrame(getWidth()/2-panel.s.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2-panel.s.getHeight(), panel.s.getWidth(), panel.s.getHeight());

    add(panel);
    validate();
}
```

My intention was to use timers to rotate the hands, but without the method that allows me to do so, I'm stuck! Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could consider using lines with a certain thickness as those tend to be way easier to draw from a point A (center of clock) to a point B (end of the hand).

Comment: Along with what Ben's suggestion you could use affine transform to handle the rotation (AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle).createTransformedShape(h)) and draw the resulting shape